# pass value of a BoundField to Javascript function by clicking a LinkButton

Tags: javascript, vb.net, gridview, eval, linkbutton

I have the following gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdResults" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grdResults_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="rowNumber"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seq">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Seq") %>' OnClientClick='<%#String.Format("alert({0},{1})", Eval("ID"), Eval("Seq")) %>'
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I would like to pass both values from `asp:BoundField` and `asp:LinkButton` to a javascript function upon a click on the LinkButton. I have tried the above code which is similar to the accepted answer of [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1856475.aspx?passing%20hidden%20filed%20values%20to%20javascript%20function) example but it doesn't work.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this instead:

```
OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("window.alert(""{0}""+""{1}"");", 
                  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID"), 
                  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Seq")) %>'
```

Comment: I'm getting the following compilation error: 'The server tag is not well formed'. If I remove the single quotes before and after {0} and {1} compilation completes but 'alert' doesn't appear.